# onEvent inside of a loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to run this loop with onEvents inside of it, but it doesn't seem to work.
I can click the button and everything works, the inner while loop keeps repeating until an onEvent is triggered, but none of the onEvents get triggered when I click on them.

```js
onEvent("startBtn", "click", function() {
  setScreen("songScreen");
  setText("songName1", "Song name: " + trackName[0]);
  setText("artistName1", "Artist name: " + artistName[0]);
  setText("pos1", "Song position: " + songPos[0]);
  setText("pop1", "Song popularity: " + songPop[0]);
  while (i < songPos.length) {
    setText("songName1", "Song name: " + trackName[i]);
    setText("artistName1", "Artist name: " + artistName[i]);
    setText("pos1", "Song position: " + songPos[i]);
    setText("pop1", "Song popularity: " + songPop[i]);
    upClick();
    downClick();

  }

});

function upClick() {
  onEvent("upImg", "click", function() {
    songLiked = true;
    console.log("test up");
    i++;
  });
}

function downClick() {
  onEvent("downImg", "click", function() {
    songLiked = false;
    console.log("test down");
    i++;
  });
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You define an event listener but you never trigger the event. Also, why are you registering the events more than once?

Comment: You don't seem to have defined `onEvent` for a start.

Comment: The user is going to click the up or down images (those are the upClick and downClick event listener functions) multiple times

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a real [mcve]

Comment: You don't modify `i` inside the `while` loop when if the JS ever gets inside that loop it is going to be stuck there because it will run that loop forever (with no opportunity to check for any events).

Comment: @sterr try to add the `function` keyword in front of the `onEvent` declaration.